# Substitute for 'InputField' in Wolfram Demonstration

Tags: manipulate, inputfield, free-form-input, demonstrations

My application relies on the ability of users to enter text, and has several settings with a huge range of potential values best entered as strings (to comply with Wolfram's admonition to "choose your controls judiciously", if nothing else). However the Wolfram Demonstrations [guidelines](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/guidelines.html) prohibit the use of `InputField` in `Manipulate`.

Is there a substitute that would allow my users to enter text and see the results of each keypress as they type?

Comment: Unless this changed, I think you can use InputField, but it is restricted (for security) to accept only numbers (numeric values) and not strings. I know the link you have says `InputField is not supported in Demonstrations.` but I think this is meant for general input. You can try it and see if it works, to accept numbers only? There is no way to input Text for a demo.

Comment: @Nasser: Unfortunately, it needs to be text. So the question remains: any (perhaps clever or tricky) approach to getting user-entered text into a Demonstration. (And, so I get it out of my system: a stupid limitation.)

Comment: You can always create custom keyboard to append/deleted characters from string attached to a variable.

Comment: @Kuba: Now that's a clever idea! Tell me more!

Comment: Well, basic idea is simple but fully functional keyboard may be a lot of work. You can start with: `DynamicModule[{input = ""},
 Panel@Column[{
    Dynamic@input,
    Row[Button[#, input = input <> #] & /@ CharacterRange["a", "z"]],
    Button["<-", input = StringDrop[input, -1]]
    }]
 ]`

Comment: @Kuba: I'll give that a try. I'd take more as an answer to this question, if you have the time.

Comment: As to "stupid limitation": This isn't stupid from a business perspective.  Allowing text input would make it possible to make a *free*  application that mimics Mathematica's functionality.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Oh I agree that there's a (characteristically Wolfram) business reason.

Comment: Well, there are about 700 developers that make their living out of this. Do you suggest they should work for free?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Of course that's what I'm suggesting. My irritation has nothing to do with already paying almost $800/year on a product that constantly throws up arbitrary limitations and requires me to figure out which of the many additional products I need to acquire to get the level of functionality that is clearly claimed by the one I've already paid (and paid and paid) for.

Comment: You did't pay anything for the CDF player, right? Your complaint was about restrictions of the free CDF player and not Mathematica itself. I also beg to differ about the "many additional products" you need to acquire. Could you provide a few examples of claimed functionality of Mathematica for which you need additional products?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: We should stop.

Comment: @Kuba: The keyboard works nicely (at least for the basic text input part), but I can't figure out how to get the variable it sets to be used in the `Manipulate`. It appears to be local to the `DynamicModule`. An answer that showed how to use the keyboard as a substitute for `InputField` in my `Manipulate` would be great!

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Try taking `input` out of the `DynamicModule` and making it a `Manipulate` variable with `{{input, ""}, ControlType -> None}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Nice! That, and the keyboard, is an answer! Now if I can figure out how to position things so the don't look like crap; and deal with all the other input that really should be be an `InputField` but can't be. (What a dumb mercenary limitation on Demonstrations functionality!)

Comment: @Kuba: Bumping again: your comments could be an answer.