# How do I size 'Button' controls to closely bound a single character?

Tags: button, size

I have a button containing a single character, generated with, for example

```
Button["X", Null]
```

but that is by default much wider than it should be:

[image]

I want the button to be much narrower, like the key of a keyboard; something like

[image]

but when I attempt to achieve that with what seems like the obvious approach using

```
Button["X", Null, ImageSize -> {25, 25}]
```

I get

[image]

which neither has the specified size, nor the shows the specified content correctly.

What am I missing? Options like `FrameMargins -> 0`, `ContentPadding -> False` don't do much. How do I get a button sized the way I'm looking for, closely bounding a single character, like a keyboard key?

---

MacBook Pro Retina (Mid 2014), OS X (10.10.2), Mathematica 10.0.2.0.

Comment: [In my machine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yaHtC.png) it shows up OK - Mma v9 Win32

Comment: also on windows 7, 10.02. It shows OK. But try `ImageSize -> Full` and see if this makes any difference.

Comment: @Nasser: `ImageSize -> Full` looks the same as the first example. It's (another) bug, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with a palette appearance for the Button, you can try this:

```
niceX = Rasterize[
   TraditionalForm["X"],
   "Image",
   ImageSize -> 10,
   RasterSize -> 75
   ];

Button[
 Style[niceX],
 FrameMargins -> 0,
 Appearance -> "Palette"
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: So `Button` doesn't work with strings?

Comment: Nice solution. (Too bad it seems necessary.)

Comment: Wait, this works also (again if "Palette" is acceptable): `Button["X", Null, ImageSize -> {20, 20}, FrameMargins -> 0, Appearance -> "Palette"]`

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I think `Appearance -> "Palette"` is sufficient, even for strings.  But buttons are system dependent.  (I'm on a Mac.)  I can't the default not to have the left and right abutting ends (which may be what they actually are). -- oh, I see you figured out the first part.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes. That seems to work.

Comment: I added the rasterized `x` so that the background would be white instead of gray, assuming this would be more preferable to you. But you know what they say about assuming. ;)

Comment: @zentient: At this point, I'll take anything!

Answer (score 3):

These options seem to be undocumented and haven't appeared on the site as far as I can see.  So maybe this is a good place to show them, as they could be used as a workaround for the OP and may be useful for others:

```
Button["X", Null, FrameMargins -> 1, 
 Appearance -> {
   "Default" -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, "GrayButton-Default.9.png"], 
   "Hover" -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, "GrayButton-Hover.9.png"], 
   "Pressed" -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Ribbons", "Common"}, "GrayButton-Pressed.9.png"]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In general, we seem to need a 7 x 28 image.  The middle column (of the image data) seems to be used as a tile. I probably don't have the edges quite right, but it produces a button-like button:

```
buttonImg[col_] := 
 Image[Graphics[{{col, EdgeForm[], 
     Rectangle[{1, 1}, {6, 27}, RoundingRadius -> 2]},
    {Black, Opacity[0.], Rectangle[{0, 27}, {3, 28}], 
     Rectangle[{4, 27}, {7, 28}]},
    {Rectangle[{0, 2}, {2, 26}], 
     Rectangle[{5, 2}, {7, 26}], {Rectangle[{2, 25}, {3, 27}], 
      Rectangle[{3, 26}, {4, 28}], 
      Rectangle[{4, 25}, {5, 27}]}, {Rectangle[{2, 1}, {3, 3}], 
      Rectangle[{3, 0}, {4, 2}], Rectangle[{4, 1}, {5, 3}]}}},
   PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 28}}], 
  ImageSize -> {7, 28}]
```

OP's example:

```
Button["X", Null, FrameMargins -> 1,
 Appearance -> {
   "Default" -> buttonImg[GrayLevel[0.98]], 
   "Hover" -> buttonImg[GrayLevel[0.9]], 
   "Pressed" -> buttonImg[RGBColor[0.5, 0.7, 1.]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

The image is resized, perhaps by tiling the middle of the image:

```
Button[X^2/(X + 1), Null, FrameMargins -> 1,
 Appearance -> {
   "Default" -> buttonImg[GrayLevel[0.98]], 
   "Hover" -> buttonImg[GrayLevel[0.9]], 
   "Pressed" -> buttonImg[RGBColor[0.5, 0.7, 1.]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, any image may be used:

```
Button["X", Null,
 Appearance -> {
   "Default" -> Image@Graphics[{Circle[]}], 
   "Hover" -> Image@Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, Disk[]}], 
   "Pressed" -> Image@Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Red, Disk[]}]}]
```

In this case, it seems to resize the image by scaling:

```
Button[(1 + y)^40 // Expand, Null,
 Appearance -> {
   "Default" -> Image@Graphics[{Circle[]}], 
   "Hover" -> Image@Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightGray, Disk[]}], 
   "Pressed" -> Image@Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Red, Disk[]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Great find. I worry that I won't be able to use undocumented features though. I'm trying to (and near giving up on) build a Wolfram Demonstration that needs quite a bit of text input, but `InputField` is prohibited in Demonstrations, and I'm experimenting with [using a keyboard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77283/37), which is where the need for buttons comes from.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Thanks.  I think that the `"Palette"` style would be quite suitable for a keyboard. Or `ButtonBar`, which shrink-wraps the buttons.

Comment: Agreed. I'm seeing what I can get going. I'm stuck on how to make use of the string it creates inside `Manipulate` though (see my last comment [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77283/37)).

Answer (score 2):

[ContentPadding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContentPadding.html):

> **ContentPadding**
>   *is an option for objects that can be displayed with frames that specifies whether the vertical margins should shrink wrap tightly around the contents.*
>
> - *A setting of ContentPadding -> False shrinks the content area tightly around the contents instead of rounding to the next full line height.*

```
Button["X", Null, FrameMargins -> 0, ContentPadding -> False]
```

[image]

compare to

```
Button["X", Null, FrameMargins -> 0]
```

[image]